# What's the difference between curious and marvel?

Tags: vocabulary

I want to express that I'm curious to new things and I have looked up in an online Chinese-English dictionary. There is a sentence:

> I marvel at all things new to me.

***My question:***

1. What's the difference between *curious* and *marvel*?
2. Does "I marvel at all things new to me" have the same meaning to "I'm curious to the new things"?

Comment: For one thing, *curious* is an adjective and *marvel* is a verb. And you would want to say, "I'm curious about new things."

Comment: You need to look up the meanings in an English dictionary. You can even do several at once: http://www.onelook.com/ If there is still doubt, edit your question to explain what it is in the references that you don't understand.

Comment: You may be interested in committing to [English Language Learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) where this question would probably be more relevant.

Answer (score 4):

No they are two different words and carry different meanings. *Curious* means *eager to learn or know something*, while *marvel* means *be amazed or surprised.*

> I am curious to know what you have in mind.
>
> She marveled at his composure.

In addition, *curious* could be used to mean something strange or unusual.

> His curious look made me worry about my job.

Comment: Marvelous answer. +1.